# What is the BGM where Pilaf starts escaping from the fortress in episode 32?

Tags: music, dragon-ball

You can hear it in episode #032, "The Flying Fortress Vanished" at around 16:17. It starts at the scene when Pilaf and his servants start escaping (as they start running out the room). You will notice that the previous track stops and the next one start then

I listened to a lot of playlists on YouTube to find this one with no luck.

I will add a screenshot of when the music starts just in case.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here (unless i heard bad and its a different song :P) 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7bVjtScRtQ

The name of the song is  Koroshi-ya Tao Paipai ("killer tao paipai")

Comment: Thanks but no unfortunatly, this is the one ending before the one I want :( if you notice in the episode, the track you mentioned finishes just before they start moving out and then a 2-3 seconds silence and the track in question starts

Comment: yeah but it seems to be the same track, at least in the english dub (but as i said i could be wrong :P)